# Replace character before expanding yasnippet

Tags: emacs, code-snippets

Is it possible to replace a character before a yasnippet is expanded?

Say that I have the following snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: foo
# key: foo
# --
~bar$0
```

I write `foo` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand it and I get `~bar` or explicitly illustrated where the first row is before expansion and the second after expansion:

```
foo[Tab]
~bar
```

Now, imagine that I want the snippet to delete any possible spaces directly before the cursor (that is 1-*n* directly preceding spaces) before the snippet is expanded.

Say that I have the following text

```
word word
```

and that I place the cursor as such

```
word [cursor]word
```

and enter the snippet key

```
word foo[cursor]word
```

now I expand the snippet by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> and I want the following to happen

```
word~bar[cursor]word
```

Notice that the space before the snippet is deleted so that the snippet is inserted directly after the first word. How can I make this happen? This does not happen with the defined snippet above. What happens is

```
word ~bar[cursor]word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with the latest yasnippet from [here](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet):

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: foo
# key: foo
# --
~bar${0:$$(save-excursion (goto-char (overlay-start (yas/snippet-control-overlay (first (yas/snippets-at-point)))))
                          (delete-char (- (skip-chars-backward " "))))}
```

Comment: It does not work I'm afraid. It inserts all the code rather than executing it. I think lisp code needs to written inside `\`` but doing that for your code gives an elisp error.

Comment: what version of yasnippet are you using? upgrade if you're not using the latest from VCS.

Comment: Also, there is very good documentation on the yasnippet project page.  Although I did have to dig through the source a little.

Comment: There is no elegant robust way to do this that I can see without $(...) support.  Is there some reason you can't upgrade?

Comment: I haven't got a reason not for upgrading except for preferring to use what's in Ubuntu's repositories. So there's no way to make this work with my version of yasnippet?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can embed some lisp code into your templates using `. So I guess you could do something like:

```
`(if (string= " " (string (preceding-char))) (backward-delete-char))`
```

Comment: I tried `${1:\`(if (string= " " (string (preceding-char))) (backward-delete-char))\`}~bar$0` but it does not behave as I want. It does not delete preceding spaces, it only places the cursor before the first letter of `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: foo
# key: foo
# --
`(delete-backward-char 1)`~bar$0
```

but usually throws a warning that a snippet modified the buffer which can be avoided by including

```
(add-to-list 'warning-suppress-types '(yasnippet backquote-change))
```

in your `config.el`.